# Tensorflow for Dart lang?

Tags: tensorflow, dart

I would like to use Tensorflow in Dart Language.

I saw in Tensorflow documentation (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/) that Dart does not cited.

Is there any initiative to develop Tensorflow APIs for Dart Lang?

Comment: Questions about external resources are discouraged on SO. This question is prone to be closed. https://gitter.im/dart-lang/TALK-general, https://plus.google.com/communities/114566943291919232850 or https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!forum/misc would be better places to ask. I haven't seen anything mentioned. Would be interesting though. The API surface doesn't look too complicated. I guess the simplest approach would be some Go or Java server that provides some REST API to be used from Dart.

Comment: As the option you can use Tensorflow without Dart.

Answer (score 4):

Not officially, although many community activities have begun to implement TensorFlow APIs using [gRPC](http://www.grpc.io/). Native bindings are less popular due to the complexities involved. Even the official C++ API is behind Python currently.

I would suggest first looking at JavaScript if you want to pursue Dart and TensorFlow, otherwise it's not likely you'll have a solution in the near future.

I've been working on a Swift API for TensorFlow, and utilizing the [Go](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/go) API, but even though these are two very popular languages, outside of Python, in the TensorFlow community, the complexity of building the APIs are proving difficult to overcome.

Comment: Why native bindings are not popular and what means a complexity? Or complexity refers specifically to TensorFlow, but all is well in all other cases with a native bindings?

Comment: Native bindings are not popular due to how difficult it is to implement a C++ binding to an API. Most other languages that are appearing with their own API efforts, such as Go, Rust, and Swift, all have decent, if not cumbersome, binding capabilities to C, but C++ adds a wealth of complexities that require a great deal of effort to get around, meaning an almost full-time project in itself.

Comment: I got an idea with this information. I conclude that I will not be able to have the state-of-the-art machine learning capabilities so briefly using Dart. I'll need to involve other languages.

Comment: We are investigating adding gRPC support, so that might be something available in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

The TensorFlow Lite Plugin for Flutter is officially available (August, 2023).
To use TensorFlow Lite Plugin you have to install it first.
Open pubspec.yaml and add tflite to dependencies

```
dependencies:
  tflite_flutter: ^0.10.3
```

Then import tflite in main.dart by adding the line

```
import 'package:tflite_flutter/tflite_flutter.dart';
```

Comment: Do we need to create the model using tensorflow core in other language first?

Comment: Yes, if you want to make an own AI then you should create a model in other language. If the model is small you can upload it directly to phone and use it in Dart through include. TensorFlow itself is a free and open-source software library, suitable for AI, machine learning and scientific calculations.